# Обновить id в одной таблицы взяв id другой таблицы

Tags: java, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть таблица phones в ней столбец idPhone, связана ключом с таблицей  log_sms столбец idPhone, необходимо взять  idPhone из phones и записать в log_sms idPhone,
есть такой запрос, но я что-то делаю не так обновляет все id таблице. Как сделать чтоб обновление было последней записи?

```
UPDATE log_sms,phones set log_sms.idPhone=phones.idPhone where PhoneNumber=?
```

Comment: А что такое "последняя запись" ? И не понятно, на основе какого поля надо выбирать запись из одной таблицы и из другой. Вы пишите что таблицы уже связаны по полю idPhone, но это значит, что в записях в обоих таблицах уже должны быть установлены правильные id на момент update

Comment: В таблицу log_sms пишутся sms и номер телефона с которого пришла sms, необходимо добавить id к последней sms

Comment: т.е. запись в log_sms уже существует, но в ней не заполнено поле idPhone ? Как тогда найти такую запись, номер телефона в этой таблице есть ? И еще раз повторяю вопрос "Что такое последняя запись ?", по какому критерию она "Последняя" ? (В SQL нет понятия порядка записей в таблице, а следовательно не существует и понятия "последняя")

Comment: Добавил скрин , необходимо взять id телефона и записать в id log_sms idPhone

Comment: А каким образом в sms_log оказалась запись без idPhone ? Вы уверены, что вам нужен именно update (изменение уже существующей записи), а не insert (добавление новой) ?

Comment: insert  не позволяет обновлять сразу две таблицы, поэтому использую update, для того чтоб связать номер телефона и sms в таблице sms_log, idPhone в таблице phone автоинкремент.

Comment: *insert не позволяет обновлять сразу две таблицы* Вы вставляете в две таблицы, в одну за другой? тогда знаете, с какими данными вставлена запись в первую - вот их и используйте как условие отбора для вставки во вторую.

Comment: Или возможно вам нужен просто `insert into sms_log(idPhone, sms)  select idPhone, 'текст сообщения' from phones where PhoneNumber=?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понимаю, происходит следующее.

Приходит некая информация об СМС, включая номер телефона. Этот телефон вставляется в таблицу телефонов, если его там нет. Затем СМС пишется в таблицу СМС, и вот тут нужен ИД записи из таблицы телефонов.

Тогда это выглядит так:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO phones (phoneNum, ...) 
VALUES ('123-45-67', ...);

INSERT INTO SMS (phoneID, sms_text, ...)
SELECT ID, 'Привет!', ...
FROM phones
WHERE phoneNum = '123-45-67';
```